# Existence of an element in the infinite dimensional normed linear space?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be an infinite dimensional normed linear space and $x^*_1, x^*_2, \dots,x^*_k$ be k linear independent elements in the dual space $X^*$. Can we find an element in $X$ such that $x^*_1(y)<0, x^*_2(y)<0, \dots,x^*_k(y)<0$?

I know this claim fails for finite dimensional spaces and maybe we should use some similar trick as in proving $\cap^k_{i=1}ker(x^*_i)\ne 0$. Can anybody show me a proof?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Nate oh~~~I should add the condition for linear independence! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the map $T : X \to \mathbb{R}^k$ defined by $Tx = (x_1^*(x), \dots, x_k^*(x))$.  I claim $T$ is surjective.  If not, let $(a_1, \dots, a_k)$ be a nonzero element of the orthogonal complement of the image $TX$.  Then $\sum_{i=1}^k a_i x_i^*(x) = 0$ for all $x$.  This means $\sum_{i=1}^k a_i x_i^* = 0$, contradicting linear independence of the $\{x_i^*\}$.  So in particular, $(-1,\dots, -1) \in TX$, meaning there is an $x$ such that $Tx = (-1,\dots,-1)$, i.e. $x_i^*(x) = -1$ for every $x$.

You don't need to assume $X$ is infinite dimensional, nor use the norm.  In fact, $X$ can be any vector space whatsoever.  (Though when $X$ has dimension less than $k$ the claim is vacuous, because in that case you can't find $k$ linearly independent elements of $X^*$.  But it's still true!)

Comment: Thank you! But how do we show that $\overline{span(TX)} \ne \mathbb{R}^k$ when we assume that the map is not surjective?I think if $\overline{span(TX)} = \mathbb{R}^k$, we still cannot find a nonzero element in the orthogonal complement

Comment: @TiWen: If $T$ is not surjective then the image $TX$ is a proper subspace of $\mathbb{R}^k$.  Since $\mathbb{R}^k$ is finite dimensional, every subspace is closed, so $TX$ is not dense.  Hence its orthogonal complement is nonempty.  This is elementary linear algebra.